# "Toggle items must be textboxes that share the same scope as the hidden item" in ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm working on drill down functionality in SSRS report with reference to tututial given at
http://ssrs2008.blogspot.in/2010/09/creating-drill-down-report-with-sql.html

But I'm getting error

> Toggle items must be textboxes that share the same scope as the hidden
>   item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item , and cannot be
>   contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope
>   has a Parent.

How can i overcome this issue? Please suggest.

Comment: Please check with " row group properties" and "details group properties" with in the group I hope you vl understand which properties you are in...!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, but I figured that I changed the wrong group properties:

> Step 4: From Row groups > select Product group details (**group
>   Details and not group header**) > go to Group Properties > select
>   Visibility tab > select Hide > click on Display can be toggled by this
>   group item and select the name of the group then click on OK

Once I change the settings for the group details it worked fine!

rg

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error after deleting a Row Group (Group16).

[rsInvalidToggleItem] The grouping ‘Group17’ has ‘Group16’ as a toggle item. Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a Parent.

Resolved the issue by doing the following:

1. **Enable Advanced Mode** by clicking the rightmost down arrow above the Column Groups window.
2. In the Row Groups window, the deleted group (Group16) appeared as (Static) under Group17. **Select (Static).**
3. In the Properties Window, ToggleItem = Group16. **Set ToggleItem to None.**

Try it.

Answer (score 1):

i think thats is the visible problem

The grouping ‘Group17’ has ‘Group16’ as a toggle item. Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the **hidden item**, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a Parent.

Try This :

```
Enable Advanced Mode by clicking the rightmost down arrow above the Column Groups window.
In the Row Groups window, Right Click at  ‘Group17’ > Group Properties
In the Properties Window, go to Visibility tab
Checklist the 'Display can be toggled by this report item:'
than chose the group of the first data example 'Purchase ID'
click ok. see thats problem is solved.
```